# How to write the below function in cognos FM(filter)

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Common.Com_macss_Account a WHERE COM_MACSS_PREMISE.prem_nb = a.prem_nb AND a.ACCT_TYPE_CD  IN  ('E', 'EO') )
```

The above expression is in BO(Universe). Need to  write it in cognos FM (Filetr). Tried CASE statement but didn't help.